# incompatible types: ArrayList<String> cannot be converted to String

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

I don't see what is wrong with my ArrayList that i get this error:

> Error:(133, 17) error: incompatible types: ArrayList cannot be
>   converted to String

i want to get all columns from table name

```
   public String getListOfFiltersName(){

        ArrayList<String> arrTblNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor c = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM  " + MyDatabase.tableFilters, null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            while ( !c.isAfterLast() ) {
                arrTblNames.add( c.getString( c.getColumnIndex("name")) );
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        c.close();
        mydb.close();
        return  arrTblNames;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of returned value `arrTblNames` is `ArrayList` but the return type of `getListOfFiltersName` is `String` Hence the error so return type of `getListOfFiltersName` method should be `ArrayList<String>` instead of `String`

```
public ArrayList<String> getListOfFiltersName(){
```

or preferably `public List<String> getListOfFiltersName(){`